# Split string before every occurrence of a character including that character

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

Basically something like this:

Input:

```py
"0101101000101011011110" #0 is the character we are splitting after
```

Output:

```py
["0", "10", "110", "10", "0", "0", "10", "10", "110", "11110"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below, every time see `'0'` append `tmp` in `result` then reset `tmp`:

```
s = "0101101000101011011110"
res = []
tmp = ''
for c in s:
    tmp += c
    if c == '0':
        res.append(tmp)
        tmp = ''
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['0', '10', '110', '10', '0', '0', '10', '10', '110', '11110']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex:

```
import re

s = "0101101000101011011110"

out = re.findall('(1*0|1+0?)', s)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rq6uGf/1)

Or:

```
out = re.split('(?<=0)(?=.)', s)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/owTGaD/1)

Output:

```
['0', '10', '110', '10', '0', '0', '10', '10', '110', '11110']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "0101101000101011011110"

out = s.replace("0", "0 ").split()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x = str1.split("0")
output = [ "0"+i for i in x]
```